# Refresh UIView for launching UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, refresh, uiimagepickercontroller

On my view, if my self.image = nil, I've to change view for that reappear UIImagePickerController like :

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; // other view
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3]; // my view
```

and it works, the UIImagePickerController reappears, but is there any method after calling my self.image = nil for refreshing the UIViewController and for showing UIImagePickerController directly ?

Here is my code :

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
self.image = nil;
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; // other view
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3]; // my view
}
```

and :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.image == nil && [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;


        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        else {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


        }

        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

            [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tabBarController layoutIfNeeded]
```

This is a method on UIView that lays out the subviews immediately. As per Apple Documentation:

> Use this method to force the layout of subviews before drawing. Using
>   the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays
>   out the view subtree starting at the root.

Comment: That doesn't work for me... I use didMoveToParentViewController, and [self.tabBarController layoutIfNeeded] doesn't work :(

Comment: Why are you calling `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];` twice? Wouldn't you only need to call it with the index you currently want to view?

Comment: I'm not calling [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; twice, In the second line I use [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3]; index:3 is the view I want to be refresh...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit the index value. But I don't think you need to call `setSelectedIndex:` twice, you should only need to call it with index 3 if that's the view you want to load.

Comment: I can't, that shows me a blank UIView and not UIImagePickerController. That doesn't consider my self.image=nil. I've to change index in order that consider my self.image=nil...